# Can I nest Ajax calls? Say to start a new xmlhttprequeset in the callback of a previous xmlhttprequest

Tags: javascript, ajax

I hava a functoin that call himself occasionally, that function has some asynchronous call to update the content of the page, but it always fails when it calls itself.

Comment: also the error message might be helpful

Comment: Firebug captured the nested ajax call, so i guess the question is the update part. Probably it is updated before i can see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

trunpet, I suggest you use setInterval instead of recursive calls.

```
setInterval(yourFunctionName,miliseconds);
```

you can even pass an annonymus function

```
setInterval(function(){
    //do your stuff here
},miliseconds);
```

whre miliseconds is the time interval betwen each call.
Something you might want to do is store the interval in a variable so you can kill it later.

```
var interval = setInterval(yourFunction,miliseconds);
clearInterval(interval);
```

warning: avoid calling it more than once without killing it first.

Comment: but it is occasionally called ,not scheduled. I can't figure out the interval because it is unpredictable.